# Case checking if value exists in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query that contains columns with just one table, let's say tableA. Inside this table a have a id, let's say tableA.id, I need to check if this tableA.id exists in another table with some where conditions, so I wrote a case statement for that, check below:

```
SELECT 
       CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM tableB B
                         WHERE A.id = B.id
                         AND B.column1 = ''
                         AND B.column2 = 'xx'
                         AND B.column3 = 'yy'
                         AND A.column4 = ''
                         AND B.column5 = 'zz01'
                         AND B.column6 = 'www'
                         AND B.column7 = '') THEN 'exists'
            ELSE 'doesnt_exists' END as result_case
FROM tableA A
```

From what I checked, the result is not checking for the WHERE conditions after the A.id = B.id, and it's mandatory, otherwise I want to get ELSE statement.

There is a reason for SQL "ignoring" the where conditions below?

I'm using MSSQL Server 2014

I'm open to others approaches.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it intentional that you are checking `AND A.column4 = ''` in amongst a load of conditions against table B? If this is not a typo, are you able to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this, as I am not aware of any scenario where SQL Server would ignore relevant conditions.

Comment: At  glance there is nothing syntactically wrong with the *where* criteria, can you demonstrate with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'm guessing your *actual* code has an `OR` somewhere

Answer (score 1):

You can use left join for doing this logic. For example:

```
SELECT 
    A.*, 
    case when B.id is null then 'doesnt_exists' else 'exists' end as result_case
from TableA A
left join TableB B 
         on  A.id = B.id  
         AND B.column1 = ''
         AND B.column2 = 'xx'
         AND B.column3 = 'yy'
         AND A.column4 = ''
         AND B.column5 = 'zz01'
         AND B.column6 = 'www'
         AND B.column7 = '';
```